# Draw a line in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, line

I want to draw a line in Crystal report. I can do that from a sub-menu but this line I need to draw in a Group section Field object with a background color property set to some color.

So whenever I draw a line it gets overlapped by this FieldObject.

How can I make sure that line would be visible over the background color of object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this through the designer, you should just be able to right-click on your line and select "Move to Front".

Comment: There is no such option for a line object.

Answer (score 1):

- Insert section below section that contains the FieldObject
- Add line to new section
- Format the first section (the one with the field object) as 'underlay following section(s)'